# MVC Ajax causing Postback outside of form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 project that I'm loading a table of records from a PartialView with Ajax. Inside of that table I have some buttons that call a jQuery function but it is causing a postback.

Below the PartialView table there is a comment section that is in a form so there is a form on the page but not where the partial view's table is being returned.

I know if it was within a form I would use the `e.preventDefault()` but I'm using an `onlcick` event on an hyperlink and using Bootstrap to make it look like a button.

Here is one of the hyperlinks and the Ajax that is called.

```
<a href="#" onclick="ApproveDeny('@item.HomeDirectory', @item.RID, 'A', '@item.ShiftDate.ToShortDateString()', '@Model.CurrentEmployeeId')" 
   class="btn btn-sm btn-success")">
    <i class="fas fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Approve
</a>


function ApproveDeny(homeDirectory, rid, arg, shift, empId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: homeDirectory + "/Exception/ExceptionApproveDeny/",
        data: { rid: rid, arg: arg, shift: shift, empId: empId },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#exceptionTable").html(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.status === 500) {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status + '\nError: Internal Server Error.');
            }
            else {
                alert('Error Code: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra closing parentheses `)` inside css classes which you can safely remove. Also, you can use a button instead of hyperlink and set its type to `button` to something like this

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="ApproveDeny('@item.HomeDirectory', @item.RID, 'A', '@item.ShiftDate.ToShortDateString()', '@Model.CurrentEmployeeId')" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <i class="fas fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Approve
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it. Not sure I understand why a button vs <a> would make a difference but if it works I'll use it. BTW, the extra ")" was a typo from me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the anchor tag is executing it's default behavior in addition to the click event. To prevent this default behavior, you could try modifying the `href` tag like so:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ApproveDeny('@item.HomeDirectory', @item.RID, 'A', '@item.ShiftDate.ToShortDateString()', '@Model.CurrentEmployeeId')" 
   class="btn btn-sm btn-success")">
    <i class="fas fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Approve
</a>
```